# How to get count of symbols which can fit editText without horizontal scrolling?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

[[image]]

I have editText which scrolls horizontally. I want to decrease text size if text doesn't fit editText without scrolling. I tried use following condition:

```
var textSize = edtResult.textSize / resources.displayMetrics.scaledDensity

    if (edtResult.width >= cardView.width && textSize > 22.0)
```

but edtResult.width returns width without scrolling

So my question:

1. How to get count of symbols which can fit editText without scrolling with current textSize?
2. Or how to get editText's width with symbols which don't fit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the [autosize TextView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview) feature (only available for API >= 26 if using `TextView`. For lower versions, use `AppCompatTextView`).